# Extensions to import ICS events to Google calendar

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-calendar, ics

Which chrome/firefox extensions or stand-alone desktop applications can allow me to add .ics events to google calendar ?

Comment: Nowadays this type of questions are off-topic in [su] but they might asked in [softwarerecs.se]. Checkout their how to ask help article first.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need an extension - [Google Calendar supports ICS files](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=34573&hl=en). Import them from  Calendar settings -> Import

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I'd say: convenience. I don't want to save an ICS file, find the place in Google Calendar to import it, re-upload the file, and finally have to remember to delete the downloaded file. I want one click operation: when an ICS file is sent to my browser I want it sent to Google Calendar with the option to discard or save the new calendar entries.

Comment: Also, I rarely want a "new calendar". Most sites that generate ICS files are producing a single event. I just want to add that event to my normal calendar, not create yet another calendar.

Comment: This is a glib an unhelpful answer.